# How to reference a file that was just checked in to source control?

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure pipeline that triggers on "check in" to TFS source control. It also runs a simple PowerShell script.

On that check in trigger I would like to also take the file that was checked in, and reference it in my PowerShell script. The file is a SQL script that I will run against a SQL server via PowerShell.

**How can I reference that checked in file within my PowerShell agent job task?** 
For example, you can reference your working folder with something like `$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)` within a PowerShell task.

And then `$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/mypath/myfile.sql` for a specific file. I assume there's some kind of "working" variable that can reference an item that just triggered a trigger.

Comment: It seems to me that you are getting source control and code generation tangled up. This seems like an anti pattern to me. I suggest that instead you just iterate through a folder and run all scripts found in there (and log the scripts that are run). When files are added and removed they are run correctly. You don't need to explicitly add them to a powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have enabled CI trigger in your build pipeline. If you just modify a file which has existed in source control, then you can use something like $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/myfile.sql in your script.

If you check in a new file (just one file), then you can get the changeset/commit included in this build in your script and fetch the file.

If you check in multiple files, that would be complicated, you need to get the changeset/commit included in this build and query the file to fetch the file you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml this has a list of all the variable available at build time either in the tasks or as environment variables in scripts.  One of them is the changeset/commit id that triggered that build "Build.SourceVersion".  With this value you can fetch any files that are part of that changeset/commit and use it in your script.

Good luck

ET